# How to run/Start a VB 6 project ( .VBp ) from another VB 6 application through code?

Tags: vb6

I have a certain VB6 add-in which needs to recursively start .vbp projects one by one, modify properties and then save and close.

I cannot use `Shell(app name)` as it needs exe, but I want to open a .vbp project.

Is there any way to do so via code?

Comment: Yes. Now did you have a real coding question?

Comment: What code have you written so far? Any error/exceptions? Where is your code failing?

Comment: Ok..I am able to launch the application using `Shell("VB6.exe /run"&Filename, vbHide)` But I was this to take place in silent mode , user should not be noticed that VB IDE has opened...
Is there a way to start VB IDE in silent mode? `VB6 /?` does not have that option

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then what you are looking to do is to modify the various files of the vb projects which is just a case processing text.

As in, find the .vbp file for each project, parse that to find the .frm, .bas etc. files etc in that project and then modify those as necessary.

Open some vb files (.vbp, .frm, .bas, .cls) with e.g. notepad and you'll quickly get an idea of what you need to do

Comment: Yes, this would be by approach if the add-in thing does not work. I was planning to use regular expression to find the string and replace them... when u open the `.ctl` or `frm` files in notepad , you can find the properties in terms of string values not as key-value pair..so some amount of key processing is needed i guess....

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [Visual Basic Command-Line Compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4kbxexc.aspx)